# Let $d(n)$ be the number of positive divisors of $n$. Find all $n$ such that $\frac{n}{d(n)}$ is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, divisor-counting-function

Let $d(n)$ be the number of positive divisors of $n$. Find all $n$ such that $\frac{n}{d(n)}=p$, a prime.

If $n=\prod_{1\leq i \leq k} p_i^{r_i}$, then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
n&=&p_1\cdot d(n)=p_1(r_1+1)(r_2+1)...(r_k+1)\\
&\ & \implies p_1^{r_1-1}p_2^{r_2}...p_k^{r_k}=(r_1+1)(r_2+1)...(r_k+1).
\end{eqnarray*} 
But I do not get any clue here. (I previously posed a question which asked only for primes but that got only one answer, which was just an observation. But now i have deleted that account of mine and have no means for it to gain attention). Can you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Good start! Can you show from your identity (or otherwise) that $p_1^{r_1-1} \le r_1+1$? Can you find all solutions to that inequality?

Comment: Only possibility i guess occurs in $r_1=2, p_1=3$, et cetera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{r_i}$ be given, where the $p_i$ are distinct primes and the $r_i$ are positive integers. You're off to a good start with the identity
$$d(n)=\prod_{i=1}^k(r_i+1).$$
From this it follows that
$$\frac{n}{d(n)}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{r_i}}{\prod_{i=1}^k(r_i+1)}=\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{p_i^{r_i}}{r_i+1}.$$
It is clear that if $\tfrac{n}{d(n)}=p$ is prime then $p\mid n$, so without loss of generality $p=p_1$. Then
$$1=\frac{n}{p_1d(n)}=\frac{p_1^{r_1-1}}{r_1+1}\prod_{i=2}^k\frac{p_i^{r_i}}{r_i+1}.$$
Now prove by induction that

> For all primes $p$ and all positive integers $r$ you have $\tfrac{p^r}{r+1}\geq 1$,
>   with equality iff $(p,r)=(2,1)$.

Can you then finish the proof using this result?